# python format list into comma separated string

Tags: python

I have a simple list

```
li=['beststreet','borocd']

print "I like strings a lot {}".format(li)
```

I want to format the list into a string but I want the output to be like this:

```
I like strings a lot beststreet,borocd
```

background: this is a simple example, I am doing string manipulation in a Class to be inserted into a SQL table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the strings in the list with a comma:

```
li=['beststreet','borocd']

print "I like strings a lot {}".format(‘,’.join(li))
```